# TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: android/support/v4/util/MapCollections$ArrayIterator.class

Tags: android

this is my project build.gradle file .whenever i run the project in android studio i get the duplicate entry: android/support/v4/util/MapCollections$ArrayIterator.class error

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion '23.0.3'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.aitsolution.bizitapp.bizit"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 14
        versionName "1.13"
        multiDexEnabled = true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
        dexOptions {
            javaMaxHeapSize "3g"
        }
    }
    lintOptions {
        checkReleaseBuilds false
        abortOnError false
    }
}
dependencies {
//    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
//    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile files('libs/linkedin-j-android.jar')
    compile files('libs/MobileOcrEngine.jar')
    compile files('libs/signpost-core-1.2.1.1.jar')
    compile files('libs/twitter4j-core-3.0.5.jar')
    compile files('libs/ksoap2_2.6.0.jar')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.6.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:+'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-appindexing:9.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.3.+'
    compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.6.1'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.4'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    compile 'com.edmodo:cropper:1.0.1'
}
```

Comment: Do u have v4-support jar in your lib folder?

Comment: He isn't loading all jars of lib directory. So, having v4-support jar shouldn't put any effect whatsoever.

Answer (score 0):

I think facebook sdk comes with v4-support library exclude that and try.

```
compile ('com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.6.0') {
    exclude module: 'support-v4'
}
```